# What GUI AutoHotKey-like program is this screenshot of?

Tags: gui

I found this screenshot on Google, but the program's title has been removed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go9YN.png]

What program is it?

Answer (score 1):

That's [vTask Studio](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/index.php), a UI automation tool.

I figured it out by going to the site that watermarked the screenshot ([tazone.net](http://www.tazone.net/)), using Chrome's translation feature to get some English words, and scrolling around until I found [the article](http://www.tazone.net/general/teamviewer-sponsored-session-auto-close/) that included that screenshot.

Comment: @dcaro Glad I could help! If my answer solved the problem, you can click the check mark next to it to show that your question is resolved.